# How can I update an existing Eloquent relationship in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to update the relationship of a one-to-many relationship in Laravel. Unfortunately I couldn't find any documentation for it. Can anyone help me?

This is what I have so far:

```
class Account extends Eloquent 
{
     public function users()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('User');
     }
}

class User extends Eloquent 
{
     public function account()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('Account');
     }
}
```

Now I am trying to update the relationship from USER(1) > ACCOUNT(50) to USER(1) > ACCOUNT(99). How would I do this? I tried the following:

```
$account = Account::find(99);

User::find(1)->account()->save($account);
```

But that doesn't work :-( Any help deeply appreciated!!

UPDATE:

The following works:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->account_id = 99;
$user->save();
```

...but there MUST be a better solution like the one above, right?

It works in many-to-many relationships with both the save() and attach() method to update the relationship between tables (from both sides of the relationship). In one-to-many relationships the attach() method doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: That's how it should work. What does "that doesn't work" mean? More details, please...

Comment: It says "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()" if I use the "User::find(1)->account()->save($account);" approach...

Comment: try User::find(1)->account->save($account);

Comment: unfortunately that also doesn't work :( it gives the following error message: "Call to a member function save() on a non-object"

Comment: hm that's an interesting question. I would like to know the answer too. In the future I will use it 100%.

Comment: I had the same experience but my problem was primary key "ID" eloquent by default was looking for "id" in small letter case and couldn't find so associate() will update foreign key as NULL. when I set primary key in my user model it works!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Taylor Otwell's official answer is the following:

```
$account = Account::find(99);
User::find(1)->account()->associate($account)->save();
```

I couldn't find the associate() method in the official docs. So if someone else is looking for a solution to this. Here you go!

Comment: The answer is now also in the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

Comment: Looks like the documentation has been moved to the master branch. http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: The docs have moved [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models)

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.html#method_associate

Answer (score 7):

This is how i would have done it

```
 //step 1
```

My migrations

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

     public function up()
     {
         Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table) {
             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
             $table->increments('id');
             $table->string('first_name');
             $table->string('last_name');
             $table->timestamps();
         });
     }

     public function down()
     {
         Schema::drop('users');
     }

 }

 class CreateUserDetailsTable extends Migration {

     public function up()
     {
         Schema::create('user_details', function(Blueprint $table) {
             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
             $table->increments('id');
             $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->unique('user_id', 'user_details_user_id');
             $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
             $table->enum('gender', array('male', 'female'))->nullable();
             $table->string('city')->nullable();
             $table->date('date_of_birth')->nullable();
             $table->timestamps();
         });
     }

     public function down()
     {
         Schema::drop('user_details');
     }

 }
```

Then

```
 //step 2
```

My base models

```
 class UserDetail extends Eloquent {

     protected $guarded = array();

     protected $table = 'user_details';

     public function user()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
     }
 }

 class User extends Eloquent {

     protected $table = 'users';

     protected $guarded = array();

     public function detail()
     {
         return $this->hasOne('UserDetail');
     }
 }
```

Then

```
 //step 3
```

My Controllers - Updating user_details schema

```
  //When Updating records i get the raw data from say an input
  $detail = Input::all();

  //then find the user
  $user = User::find(1);

  //then update the details
  $detail = $user->detail()->update($detail);

  //then respond back with the detail
  Response::json($detail);
```

My Controllers - creating user_details schema

```
  //again get data input from source, the source does not come with user id
  $detail = Input::all();

  //when creating new record
  $detail = new UserDetail($detail);
  $detail = $user->detail()->save($detail);
  return Response::json($detail);
```

And thats it for creating and updating new records using Laravel 4's belongsTo relationships

Comment: well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Hey you can refer the laravel docs for the solution.

Link http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models

```
$account = Account::find(10);

$user->account()->associate($account);

$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

**

Try

```
$user = User::find();
$account = Account::find()->user()->save($user)
```

My apologies, I didn't understand what was trying to be accomplished.

Comment: this works of course. but i am trying to alter the relationship from the user side, based on the user, not the account. which shouldn't be a problem and works in other ORMs. so instead of telling Eloquent to assign a new user to the account I want to tell it to assign a new account to the user, thus: User::find(1)->account()->save(Account::find(99)); Don't worry about the terminology. It could be apples and bananas as well. I just need to find a way to update relationships from both sides without assigning the foreign_id manually like described above.

Comment: Ok well between the method I provided, and the user->account_id method you gave, you have covered editing the account info from both ends.  If you are just trying to change the users account id and nothing else then the method you gave should work fine.

Comment: It doesn't make sense though since it perfectly works in a many-to-many relationship. If for example an account can have multiple users and a user can belong to multiple accounts the relationship can be updated by either using `User::find(1)->accounts()->attach(Account::find(99))` OR by using `Account::find(99)->users()->attach(User::find(1))`. This should also be the case for one-to-many relationships. I don't see a point why it shouldn't.

Comment: Many to many relationships are different in that they rely on the pivot table, so the relationship is accessible from both sides.  In the situation you gave the key is only on one table, and thus can only be accessed from that one direction.

Comment: Sam, it really should be the task of an "Eloquent" ORM to detect the relationship and then build the appropriate SQL to alter the database. There is no point on setting up relationships otherwise. Of course the key is only on one table, but Eloquent should be well aware of that since the relationship has been set-up in the models (hasMany / belongsTo). So either way the ORM should be able to generate the correct SQL. I have used other ORMs that do this without a doubt...

Comment: Ok well regardless of the confusion we seem to be having.  If all you are trying to do is edit the users account id then the method you gave is the best.

Doing something like user::find->account()->save($account) is doing to much work for a simple task.  This is going to do 2 separate querys to change on thing. You say there must be a better way like this is not already incredibly convenient vs vanilla php.

I certainly do not mean to be rude in any sense, I'm just rather confused by the task trying to be accomplished.

Comment: Well, the point of using an ORM is generating SQL via objects. So why not have a convenient method to tell one object to link to another object without having to juggle with foreign keys? And I guess if someone is concerned about the number of queries performed it's better not to use an ORM at all. Since actually User::find() is already performing an unnecessary query when the goal is only to update an existing resource.

Comment: Yeah but all you are trying to do is change the users account id, why would you need to make querys to the account model using->account();  There is nothing in that model you are changing, and nothing to dynamically access. So in this case you can access it using the way you described from the users side, or from the account side in the way I gave.

You say you want to have a convenient method without having to juggle foreign keys, so open the given users model and update his account id directly like you said originally.