# Laravel One-To-Many insertion on a Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-5.3

I am using **Laravel 5.3** ad having issues on saving through the `hasMany` relationship.

I have tables employee and activity which has One-to-Many Relation i.e Each employee will perform many activities.

When I am adding activities against employee using `associate()` it send me an error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::associate()
```

Below are the DB structure and code:

**Database structure:**

```
employee (1st table)
– employee_id
– employee_name
- created_at
- updated_at

activity (2nd table)
– activity_id
– activity_name
- created_at
- updated_at

employee_activity (pivot table)
– employee_activity_employee_id
– employee_activity_activity_id
```

**Model Class Employee:**

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'employee';
    protected $primaryKey = 'employee_id';

    public function activity() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Activity', 'employee_activity', 'employee_activity_employee_id', 'employee_id');
    }
}
```

**Model Class Activity:**

```
class Activity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'activity';
    protected $primaryKey = 'activity_id';

    public function employee() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Employee', 'employee_activity', 'employee_activity_activity_id' ,'activity_id');
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function EmployeeActivityAssociation()
{
    $employee_id = Input::get('employee_id');
    $activity_ids = Input::get('activity_id'); // This is an array of activities
    $employee = Employee::find($employee_id);
    if (!empty($employee)) {
         //Adding activity under the employee
        foreach ($activity_ids as $id) {
            $activity = Activity::find($id);
            $employee->activity()->associate($activity);
            $employee->save();
        }
        return 'Activities asscoiated to employee';
    }   
    else {
        return 'Employee not found';
    }
}
```

*Do I have my relationship defined incorrectly here?*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868838/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderassociate this can help you.

Comment: it is many to many.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your relation is not defined correctly. By seeing your table structure it should be [`many-to-many`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Model Class Employee:

```
public function activity() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity', 'employee_activity', 'employee_activity_employee_id', 'employee_id');
}
```

Model Class Activity:

```
public function employee() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Employee', 'employee_activity', 'employee_activity_activity_id' ,'activity_id');
}
```

SO your controller should be as:

```
public function EmployeeActivityAssociation()
{
    $employee_id = Input::get('employee_id');
    $activity_ids = Input::get('activity_id'); // This is an array of activities
    $employee = Employee::find($employee_id);
    if (!empty($employee)) {
        $employee->activity()->attach($activity_ids);
      return 'Activities asscoiated to employee';
    }   
    else {
        return 'Employee not found';
    }
}
```

If you want to stick to one-to-many relation then you have to change your table schemas as:

Remove table `employee_activity` table and add column `employee_id` in activity table then define relation according to [one-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

Use a many-to-many scheme, and on migrations, define the field 'activity_id' as 'unique' on table 'employee_activity':

```
$table->unsignedInteger('employe_id');    
$table->unsignedInteger('activity_id')->unique();
```

In this way, you can register on 'employee_activity' table only one activity associated with one employe, and one employe can be associated with many activities. Otherwise, a unique error will be generated.